# Unable to fix broken CSS which once worked

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I am having a lot of trouble with this CSS in a large community wiki I run. It used to work just fine but has since stopped using the specified background image for the wiki and has broken the page formatting for the main page.

I was not the one to design the CSS, but was provided with it be a generous volunteer. The code is below, but I don't even know what is broken and what is not.

```
.body { 
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Vb4KDsz.jpg");
background-position: top center;
margin:auto;
}

.WikiaPageContentWrapper {
background: #eadfbb;
border: 2px solid #0f1620;
}

.WikiaPageContentWrapper:before {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
bottom: 35px;
padding-left: 115px;
content: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jg7GHkG.png");
}

#WikiaArticle:before {
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
left: -210px;
content: url("http://i.imgur.com/LVeNyOJ.png");
}
.WikiaPage { border: 0 }
```

To actually address the problem, it would be easier to link the wiki and you can see for yourself that the CSS only actually inserts the final part of code. Here is the [link](http://rollplaydnd.wikia.com/wiki/Rollplay_Wiki)

For example, the main page is very oddly formatted depending on your screen resolution, and the background image specified in the CSS has been replaced by a grey background, along with the second image in the above code.

---

For some reason, after fiddling with the first answer, it caused something to change and the background to be restored. While the background itself is fixed, the page is far too wide, which is the formatting problem I addressed earlier. The new/old code is:

```
.i18ndoc {
background-color: #FFF77D;
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 8pt;
height: 140px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 3px;
}

body.mediawiki{
background:url("http://i.imgur.com/W23xCc6.jpg") repeat-x fixed center top #0f1620;
}
.WikiaPageContentWrapper {
background: #eadfbb;
border: 2px solid #0f1620;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.WikiaPageContentWrapper:before {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 170px;
content: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jg7GHkG.png");
}
#WikiHeader:before {
position: absolute;
top: 270px;
left: -200px;
content: url("http://i.imgur.com/LVeNyOJ.png");
}
.WikiaPage {
border: 0 !important;
}
footer {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.infobox tr {
line-height: 1em;
}
.infobox tr img {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

With that fixed (thanks for the help) how do I reduce the width of the screen? If you go to the homepage of [link](http://rollplaydnd.wikia.com/wiki/Rollplay_Wiki) you can see the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why is that `#WikiaArticle:before {` commented out? HAHA kidding. I'm tired.

Comment: As far as I can tell this all looks fine. Can you please provide more information regarding the issue you're having? Any errors being presented perhaps.

Comment: We need the link to the page in question.

Comment: Based on the images, it seems to be http://rollplaydnd.wikia.com/.

Comment: Indeed it is. I was absent for a while and the CSS broke :(

Comment: The body background-image in the URL you posted isn't loading: http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb62505/rollplaydnd/images/archive/5/50/. It shows a 403 error, that's why you get a gray background.

Comment: yes, but the image link itself is not broken, within the actual CSS code, and I even re-uploaded the image from my personal files and tried that but got the same result, as clicking the link shows. http://i.imgur.com/Vb4KDsz.jpg

Comment: I still see the image URL I posted. If I try yours, it works. The image isn't perfect, but it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because Wikia recently renamed a few of their classes with the recent Fluid Layout features they implemented a few weeks ago.

All you need to do is change `.body` to `body.background-dynamic.skin-oasis` and your background will show up again.

That being said, you will probably have other issues related to the Fluid Layout changes that have completely fubar'd something or another. If you notice anything else please contact me on my [MessageWall](http://community.wikia.com/wiki/Message_Wall%3aRyaNayR)
at Community Central. I'll be more than happy to assist you with anything you need.

Comment: Sadly it seems to have been ineffectual. The background remains off-blue.

Comment: You didn't put in the entire selector, it's `body.background-dynamic.skin-oasis` not `.background-dynamic.skin-oasis`. Make sure to copy that **exactly** as is.

Comment: I did it and it fixed it, but if you look now, there appears to be something else seriously wrong in that the formatting is destroyed as was addressed in the main post. Thanks for the help with that, but do you have any idea how I could fix it? Also, it seems to repeat the image rather than be continuous as it was before.

Comment: Hmm, considering all the extra stuff they added, you might be best off doing this:

Add this to MediaWiki:Wikia.js:
`$('body').removeClass('background-not-tiled background-dynamic');`

And then replace the first block in MediaWiki:Wikia.css with this:
`html { background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Vb4KDsz.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover #000; }
body { background: none; }`


It may seem kind of unnecessary to use javascript but trust me, it's much easier than re-styling about 20 new selectors in the CSS.

Comment: Edited in response. I tried what you suggested, but it seemed rolling back some changes fixed it. I was wondering if you could help me with the current strange dimensions of the wiki, please

Comment: If you mean the width of the main content, I think this will do what you want: `.WikiaHeader .page-width-container, .WikiaPage { margin: 0 289px; }` increasing the second number will make the content narrower, while lowering it will make it wider. 289px seems to be the limit before it starts squeezing the text in the article. (By the way, the default is 170px.)

Comment: I tried this, but whether I input it wrongly, or something, it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: Scratch that, it worked perfectly! You solved it all, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you have to wait a while for the server cache to update before you can see the result of any changes made in CSS or JS. Glad it worked though!

Comment: @Allegate Oh and in response to your comment: `"I tried what you suggested, but it seemed rolling back some changes fixed it."` 

I think the reason that worked is because the version you rolled back to is using `body.mediawiki` to set the background, and the reason it works is because you are still using the javascript code I gave earlier (it's still in your MediaWiki:Wikia.js) — What it does is remove the `.background-dynamic` class from the body of the page, which previously would have prevented `body.mediawiki` from having any effect, as it adds a ton of CSS rules that override the others.